# Primefaces + jQuery + Triangle Icon (THAT DOESN'T SHOW)!

Tags: jquery, html, primefaces, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using primefaces with jQuery (I guess since I have this line in the template I'm using)

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head"/>
```

So it's supposed that when I use this: (from [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml))

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true">
    <p:tab title="Godfather Part I">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />
            <h:outputText
                value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Godfather Part II">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />
            <h:outputText value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Godfather Part III">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />
            <h:outputText value="After a break of more than 15 years...." />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

I should see a full usable accordion. Well, I get it, everything but the triangle icon.

Inspecting, I found the span that is rendered in each of the tabs like this:

```
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all tab-in-accordion" role="tab" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
    Godfather Part I
</h3>
```

Issue is in `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>` but the class `ui-icon-triangle-1-e` in chrome inspector does not show up. I've read and I know that class is the one that gives the background and position (using the icons from jquery).

How can I fix this and have the triangle showing up?

Answer (score 5):

It is an issue with the theme definition with bootstrap theme.css. If you inspected the CSS, you would note it. Add the following to your main css file to make the triangle icon visible.

> .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon {
>       display: block; }

Comment: not working, it's like class `ui-icon` does not exist at all, is that the one that has the background property, right?

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need to insert the jquery , this is made automatically by primafaces...

Unless you are triyng to do a different thing, like work with a other version of jquery and primefaces jquery at same time.

Try to remove this  and run again. If does not work, you probably are having a theme definition problem...

By the way, if you use the primefaces tags in your jsf page, you will be able to use the built-in jquery of primefaces to do you r own jquery codes.

Edited:

By default primafaces use the aristo theme, that are already inside the primefaces package,

I think that set a theme can solve your situation, let´s try to download it and set it in web.xml...

If you are using maven, do the following:

1- Insert this dependency in maven

```
<dependency>    
<groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>    
<artifactId>aristo</artifactId> 
<version>1.0.8</version> 
</dependency>
```

2- In your web.xml :

```
<context-param>     
<param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>   
<param-value>aristo</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Comment: Hi @ryegros, I just removed the `<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head"/>` from the template, everything keeps working but triangle icon is still not there.

Comment: Can you see the following line added to your rendered page? `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="=.../javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo">   `

Comment: All I see in CSS is: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/STAR-web/ui/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0" />`